# Tag links not hidden by spoilers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Links to tags are not hidden by spoilers:

> [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) are issues in spoilers

For a start **why?** I don't see what purpose being able to see the outline of a tag (it is more visible on other sites) when all other pieces of text are hidden.

It has proved problematic in several cases, especially on Puzzling, where hidden answers are imperative 90% of the time.

Also **can this be changed?** I don't want to cause a massive fuss, so if this is too big to sort out, then don't worry about it.

Comment: @NathanTuggy oh that didn't pop up in the related so I assumed this hadn't been asked yet